# How long it take to doing mousedown and mouseup on javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousedown, mouseup

I have a code to calculate how long it takes from mousedown to mouseup. After I click mouse I will know time that needed from previouse moouse up. Everythings work fine, unless for first click. I know it doesn't work because i put `startTime`into `mouseup` event, we don't do mouseup when the first click right ? any other idea?

Here is the code:

```
var startTime, endTime;

$(".btn-number").on('mousedown', function () {
    endTime = new Date().getTime();

    if (endTime - startTime < 250) {
        longpress = false;
        console.log('< 250');
    } else if (endTime - startTime >= 300) {
        longpress = true;
        console.log('>= 300');
    }

});

$(".btn-number").on('mouseup', function () {
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
});
```

Comment: Try putting `startTime = new Date().getTime();` at the beginning. Like `var startTime = new Date().getTime(), endTime;`

Comment: mousedown happens before mouseup and both occur within a click. Logic here looks backwards

Comment: defining `startTime` in the bigining means calculate `startTime` when the first page loaded, so the first mouseup is calculated from the first page load

Comment: but you aren't defining startTime on page load. Provide a proper description of what you are trying to do and what this will be used for

Comment: The code looks like you are trying to track the time the mouse button is held down (but you have the events reversed.) However, the description of the problem sounds like you are trying to track the time _between clicks_. Which is it?

Answer (score 4):

I am not able to comment, otherwise this answer is just comment worthy, just interchange mouseup and mousedown

```
var startTime, endTime,i=0;

$(".btn-number").on('mouseup', function () {
    endTime = new Date().getTime();

    if (endTime - startTime < 250) {
        longpress = false;
        console.log('< 250');
    } else if (endTime - startTime >= 300) {
        longpress = true;
        console.log('>= 300');
    }
    console.log('\n' + i++);
});

$(".btn-number").on('mousedown', function () {
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g1x9e7xh/

Comment: Looks like a perfectly fine answer to me, including declaring `i`. The listeners could be chained though.

Comment: it just calculates how long mousedown takes.

Comment: @BayuAnggara if you are working towards calculating the difference between newMouseUp and prevMouseUp, there will be no value in the first output.